# Where can I get a longer mouse?

Tags: mice

I'm looking for a mouse that's longer than the traditional standard mouse.

Reason: I'm beginning to get minor pains in the forefinger and middle finger of each hand. (I swap hands frequently as soon as I feel any pain from one hand.)

I've discovered that if I use a STRAIGHT finger (rather than a curved finger) to press a button, the pain almost disappears in any hand.

Normally, my finger would contact the mouse on the TIP of the finger. But if I use a straight finger, I'm touching the button with the pad of my finger, very close to the first joint nearest the fingertip. So, my straight finger actually overhangs the front of the mouse, by about 1cm.

So, I'm looking for a mouse that's about 1cm longer than the traditional mouse. (It would also need to be symmetrical, in other words it can be used with either hand.)

The following Google search found nothing. The purpose of "-mat" was to eliminate the thousands of extra long mouse mats.

```
extra long mouse OR mice -mat
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us how long is your current mouse.

Comment: The distance from the most protruding rear point to the most protruding front point is 11.5 cm (4.5 in)

Comment: It sounds like you need a mouse designed for a palm grip, rather than a claw grip. Are your hands so big that a palm grip style is also unsuitable?

Comment: I hadn't heard of any of these terms, so I looked here: https://candid.technology/mouse-grips-compared-palm-vs-claw-vs-tip-grip/   Claw: "...only the tip of the fingers ... is used to make contact with the mouse." Fingertip:  "...only the tips of the fingers are used ..." So, the only remaining type is Palm Grip, which sounds to me like the traditional grey MS mouse of 50 years ago. My current mice are based on MS. AFAIK, my hands are average size. If I hold the mouse with my fingers arched and not protruding over the end, I can push a pencil through the arch.

Comment: ....I don't want ANY gap between the underside of my fingers and the mouse. I've ordered the Anker, so I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be looking for an **Ergonomic Mouse**.

Those are the mice that are longer and/or physically laid out for improved arm and finger positioning.

Products like the [**Logitech MX Master 2S Wireless Mouse**](https://amzn.to/2XlY4HP) or the (cheaper) [**Anker Ergonomic Optical Wired Vertical Mouse**](https://amzn.to/2WPFSCk)

Comment: I've tried some of these in various computer shops. (I actually have the Anker waiting in my Amazon basket.) It seems to me that they are all intended to be pressed with the tip of a curved finger. [BTW: both of your links point to the Anker mouse. If I hover over the link and look at lower left, the targets are not https targets, but they are different. I can find the page with the link text, of course, but I'll preserver my current page in case some interested techie wants me to investigate further.]

Comment: This is the picture Anker shows of the usage https://i.imgur.com/M4Abtus.jpg doesn't look curved to me

Comment: With this latest page (which has both of my answers), the Logitech link now loads the Logitech page. My older page is still preserved, and still loads the Anker page.

Comment: that looks good to me. The important feature is that the mouse is in continuous contact with the underside of the user's finger - rather than at a much smaller area of the fingertip. Less area means greater pressure. Greater pressure means greater stress on any of the knuckle joints, and greater pain.

Comment: The Anker mouse recommended by @Yisroel Tech is great. I no longer have pains in my right forefinger or middle finger. I'm now looking for a left-handed similar mouse. Anker don't sell these. I think it's vital to keep switching hands at regular intervals BEFORE any pain starts - rather than AFTER the pains start.

Comment: Left-hended mice are not that common altogether so there are not a lot of options. You might take a look at https://www.amazon.com/Evoluent-VM4L-VerticalMouse-Ergonomic-Connection/dp/B0046ZN8P4/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_147_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=5GQMDFAP1G33P7JTNND4 which is also "Ergonomic" with a similar layout.